# Why does DOS set the SP register to 0xFFFE after loading a .COM file?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, callstack

On the wikpedia page about .COM files https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file it reads:

*.COM files in DOS set all x86 segment registers to the same value and the SP (stack pointer) register to 0xFFFE, thus the stack begins at the very top of the memory segment and works down from there.*

But this actually sets the stack to begin one word below the top of the segment. When pushing a value on the stack the CPU will decrement SP to 0xFFFC and store the value there, thus wasting the top word of the segment. What is the reason for DOS not setting SP to 0 instead?

Comment: DOS stores a pointer to an `int 20h` instruction there so you can exit your program by issuing a `ret` instruction.

Comment: Also note that if less than 64 kB of memory are available for your process, `SP` can be initialised with lower values than `FFFE`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This is for compatibility with CP/M.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200309-00/?p=103547)

In CP/M you could simply return from your program using `ret` and your program would exit cleanly. This was achieved by having a `0x0000` at the top of the stack, and having an `int 20h` instruction at address `0x0000`. Even though `int 20h` is DOS' official way to quit a program, the option to quit the program using `call 0` was kept from CP/M, and the outermost-scope `ret` works the same as well since it returns to `0`.

In order to have that `0x0000` word at the top of the stack, you need to start the usable stack 2 bytes further down, obviously. That's why `SP` is initially at `0xFFFE`, pointing to that `0x0000` word which in turn points to the `int 20h` instruction.